# What needs to be paid in cash on an all-inclusive Egypt vacation?

Tags: money, exchange, egypt

I'm travelling to Egypt this month for a weeks honeymoon and staying in an all-inclusive resort in Sharm El Sheik. I do not require taxi money, transfer is included nor do I want any excursions. I will have a credit card for emergencies but would rather not incur the oversea usage fee. So far I could think about two things that would require some cash:

- Upgrading the restaurant once or twice
- Tipping staff on departure

How much would that typically cost in Egypt? What else would need to be paid in cash?

Comment: $2125: $2000 for  this amazing golden ring for your wife and $125 your for tips.

Comment: Sorry I voted to close the answer really is opinion based. If you would ask if it is common to tip staff, it would be more appropriate for this platform

Comment: @andra I'm asking for costs I have not anticipated.

Comment: I understand, but the answer can really go in different directions. You could say 0, because why bother about tipping and you seem to have covered all, or you could say a high number because you didn't anticipated buying a ring, or I could suggest taking another credit card, both my MC and AMEX card don't charge me abroad.

Comment: Take 1000 Egyptian pounds, that will do for a week (tipping and snacks or so)

Comment: I tried to edit the question to make it more acceptable to the naysayers, please let me know what you think. @Paul you might want to specify the price class/type of resort if you have more info about that.